# Four character extension files will not download in deployment

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, file, web-applications

I have a web application written in visual basic.  I am trying to download files from the database; which works fine for any file with 3 characters in its extension.  Any four character responds with a 'page not found' in the deployed version.  In the development version the both file types download correctly.  Looking for any information to help.

Here is a bit of the code (note: this executes on a button click event):

```
    Dim myDataReader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    myDataReader = Me.SqlCommandFileGrab.ExecuteReader

    myDataReader.Read()

    'check for null file content
    If myDataReader.GetValue(1) Is System.DBNull.Value Then
        Response.Write(ClientScripts.ShowAlert("No attachment found."))
        myDataReader.Close()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'check download directory

    Dim myDir As System.IO.DirectoryInfo

    myDir = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("Temp\") + Session("loginUser"))

    If Not myDir.Exists Then
        myDir.Create()
    End If

        'get file location

        Dim FilePath As String
        Dim FileExt As String
        Dim File As String

        File = myDataReader.GetValue(0).ToString
        FileExt = File.Substring(File.LastIndexOf(".") + 1)
        FilePath = Server.MapPath("Temp\") + Session("loginUser") + "\SaveFile." + FileExt

    'download file

    Dim myFile As New System.IO.FileStream(FilePath, IO.FileMode.Create)
    Dim stWriter As New System.IO.BinaryWriter(myFile)

    stWriter.Write(myDataReader.GetValue(1))

    myFile.Close()
    stWriter.Close()
    myDataReader.Close()

    'display file
    Dim httpPath As String
    httpPath = "Temp/" + Session("loginUser") + "/SaveFile." + FileExt
    Response.Write(ClientScripts.OpenLink(httpPath))
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the file is written to the appropriate directory on the server?

Comment: Maybe not any sort of solution to your problem, but the System.IO Name space has quite a few methods for constructing file paths and file name manipulation which might be more robust than the string concatenations that you're using now